# How can you multiply numbers in string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I misunderstood my homework assignment so I am trying to fix it. Here is the assignment

-- For a two lap race, calculate the race time. To do that, you would need to multiply the user input of lap time and multiply it by 2 to get race time.

Is it possible to do it in string?

Here is a sample of what I have so far. Please disregard `race_time` variable description. I thought race time and lap time were the same, but they are not. I want to do something like...

`race_time1 * 2`

to obtain the race time result as the output.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;


int main(){

    string car_number1;
    string car_number2;
    string car_number3;

    string car_color1;
    string car_color2;
    string car_color3;

    string race_time1;
    string race_time2;
    string race_time3;

    cout<<"We are doing a 2 lap race." << ' ' ;

    //Data for car 1

    cout<<"Enter a number for the first race car: ";
    cin>>car_number1;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Enter a color for car number " << car_number1 << endl;
    getline(cin,car_color1);
    cout<<"Enter a lap time in MM:SS: for the "  << car_color1  <<' '<<          car_number1  << ' '<< "car" << endl;
    getline(cin,race_time1);

    cout<<"You have entered a"<<' '<< car_number1<<' '<<car_color1<<' '<< "car with a lap time of" << ' ' << race_time1 <<endl;
```

Comment: Why are you using strings? Simply `int a; cin >> a` would have done the trick

Comment: Save yourself the trouble, use `int` from the start.

Comment: And even if you do read strings first, there's `std::stoi`

Comment: It is unclear what kind of input you need to be able to parse. Provide example input and expected output, that would clarify things a lot.

Comment: Hello! So what I have done already was create 3 cars where the user can input the data. Then the output tells the user who won based off the lap times placed, and it needs to tell the user what the race time was. My trouble is that I have used string to define my variables, and I do not know how to multiply the lap times by 2 in order to get my race time.

Answer (score 0):

Classic class operator overloading and class definition, I am sure you might have lot of doubts. Why so complex but there are lot of details and simplicity of use involved in it.

```
// Test1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Lap_time class represents minutes and seconds
struct lap_time {
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    // Default constructors
    lap_time() : minutes(0),seconds(0) { }
    lap_time(const string& str) { 
        stringstream ss(str);
        string value;
        if (std::getline(ss, value, ':'))
            minutes = stoi(value);
        if (std::getline(ss, value, ':'))
            seconds = stoi(value);
    }

    lap_time(int m, int s) : minutes(m), seconds(s) { }


    // input operator overload
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, lap_time&);

    // output operator overload
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, lap_time&);

    // Time multiply operation
    lap_time operator*(const int& x) {
        int time = (this->minutes) * 60 + this->seconds;
        time = time * 2;
        return lap_time(time / 60, time % 60);
    }

};


// input operator overload declaration
istream& operator>>(istream& is, lap_time& lt)
{
        string laptime;
        is >> laptime;
        stringstream ss(laptime);
        string value;
        if (std::getline(ss, value, ':'))
            lt.minutes = stoi(value);
        if (std::getline(ss, value, ':'))
            lt.seconds = stoi(value);
        return is;
}

// ouput operator overload declaration
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, lap_time& lt)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << lt.minutes << ":" << lt.seconds;
    os << ss.str();
    return os;
}

// getline function overload to read lap_time 
void getline(std::istream& is, lap_time& lt)
{
    string laptime;
    is >> laptime;
    stringstream ss(laptime);
    string value;
    if (std::getline(ss, value, ':'))
        lt.minutes = stoi(value);
    if (std::getline(ss, value, ':'))
        lt.seconds = stoi(value);
}

int main()
{
    string car_number1;
    string car_number2;
    string car_number3;

    string car_color1;
    string car_color2;
    string car_color3;

    lap_time race_time1;
    lap_time race_time2;
    lap_time race_time3;

    cout << "We are doing a 2 lap race." << ' ' << endl;

    //Data for car 1

    cout << "Enter a number for the first race car: " << endl;
    cin >> car_number1;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter a color for car number " << car_number1 << endl;
    getline(cin, car_color1);
    cout << "Enter a lap time in MM:SS: for the " << car_color1 << ' ' << car_number1 << ' ' << "car" << endl;
    getline(cin, race_time1);
    cout << "Single Lap race time is :" << race_time1 << endl;
    // I do not think you should multiply by two unless assuming both laps equal timing.
    cout << "Two lap race time is : " << (race_time1 * 2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hello all! So I knew I should have used int for my lap times in order to properly multiply it by 2 to get my lap time. I didn't know how to do it, but I figured out what I was missing. I should have coded using namespace std; which would allow me to add int and keep my strings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use function like this:

```
template<typename IntFunction>
std::string transform_numbers_in_string(std::string text, IntFunction func)
{
    auto cond = [](auto& x) {return std::isdigit(x);};
    for (auto it = std::find_if(text.begin(), text.end(), cond);
              it != text.end();
              it = std::find_if(it, text.end(), cond))
    {
        std::string before, after;
        auto pos = it - text.begin();
        std::size_t i;
        for(i=0; cond(*(it+i)); ++i)
            before += *(it+i);
        after = std::to_string(func(std::atoll(before.c_str())));
        text.replace(pos, i, after);
        it = text.begin() + pos + after.size();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Example program:

```
int main()
{
    auto lambda1 = [](const auto& x) {return x*2;};
    auto lambda2 = [](const auto& x) {return x*x;};
    auto lambda3 = [](const auto&  ) {return 666;};

    std::string text {"I have 3 dogs and 4 cats and 5 hamsters."};
    std::cout << text << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << transform_numbers_in_string(text, lambda1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << transform_numbers_in_string(text, lambda2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << transform_numbers_in_string(text, lambda3) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
I have 3 dogs and 4 cats and 5 hamsters.

I have 6 dogs and 8 cats and 10 hamsters.
I have 9 dogs and 16 cats and 25 hamsters.
I have 666 dogs and 666 cats and 666 hamsters.
```

Comment: I'm not sure a template function like that is very useful for someone, who is very clearly doing a *very* basic programming exercise, and can barely grasp C-like syntax...